# Android architecture: is RemoteMediator a DataSource itself for the repository class?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-paging-3, remote-mediator

I'm learning how to implement **Paging** (Jetpack Paging Library) and how to fetch data from both network and local database.

I have followed Google [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-paging) and learned about the `RemoteMediator` class, which is very useful for me, because it handle network requests when data is needed, in an endless list.

Until now, I used a `Repository` with a `NetworkDataSource` and a `LocalDataSource` (and mappers), but with the mediator I'm confused about the correct usage, see code below.

```
class MainRepository(
    private val networkDataSource: NetworkDataSource,
    private val localDataSource: LocalDataSource,
    private val listMapper: ListMapper<Results, Entity>
) {
    
    fun getDatasStream(): Flow<PagingData<Entity>> {

        val pagingSourceFactory = {
            localDataSource.getDatas()
        }

        @OptIn(ExperimentalPagingApi::class)
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(pageSize = NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE, enablePlaceholders = false),
            remoteMediator = DatasRemoteMediator(
                networkDataSource,
                localDataSource,
                listMapper
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = pagingSourceFactory
        ).flow
    }

    companion object {
        const val NETWORK_PAGE_SIZE = 20
    }
}
```

As you can see, the repository create and pass the mediator to the `Pager` class, instantiated on function *getDatasStream*.

The code above is it correct? Or should I have to change the constructor of the repository in order to have only the **DatasRemoteMediator** as parameter and consider this class as the man in the middle?